# Understanding YouTube Data API Quota Consumption - API Unit Costs per Request

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am currently working with the YouTube Data API to retrieve video data based on specific parameters using the search endpoint. While making requests, I noticed that each call to the API consumes a certain number of "API units" from my quota. (eg: if I request 1 api call it takes 100 units from daily api limit of "youtube data API")

I would like to gain a better understanding of the API unit costs for various parameters in the search endpoint. Specifically, I am interested in knowing the number of API units each parameter typically consumes in a single call.

Here is an example of the API call I am making:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=***&maxResults=50&order=date&videoDuration=medium&type=video&access_token=****`

For the above API request, how are the API units calculated for each parameter? What is the API unit cost for the following parameters:

part=snippet
channelId
maxResults
order
videoDuration
type

Additionally, are there any other factors that can affect the API unit costs in this particular API call? I want to ensure that I manage my API usage efficiently and avoid reaching the quota limits unexpectedly.

Any insights or information on how the API unit costs are determined and how to optimize API calls within the quota limits would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!